# How to change elastic beanstalk environment type from load-balanced to single instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk environment that uses a load-balancer. It is also has a http to https configuration. I want to change the environment type from load-balanced to single instance (because I realized I'm not using the app as much and the costs are running high). I tried to do so by going to configuration settings, capacity settings and switch from the load-balancer option to the single instance option.
Firstly, I get a warning "Migrating to a single-instance environment replaces all of your current instances and reduces your capacity." with this code.
`aws:elasticbeanstalk:environment:EnvironmentType "LoadBalanced" => "SingleInstance"`

And then it fails with this error
`Service:AmazonCloudFormation, Message:Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [AWSEBV2LoadBalancer] in the Resources block of the template`

The only file in my ebextensions folder is a http to https configuration file with this code

```
Resources:
 AWSEBV2LoadBalancerListener:
  Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
  Properties:
    LoadBalancerArn:
      Ref: AWSEBV2LoadBalancer
    Port: 80
    Protocol: HTTP
    DefaultActions:
      - Type: redirect
        RedirectConfig:
          Host: "#{host}"
          Path: "/#{path}"
          Port: "443"
          Protocol: "HTTPS"
          Query: "#{query}"
          StatusCode: "HTTP_301"
```

And then a "FAILED TO DEPLOY CONFIGURATION"

Comment: I tried to do this a while ago. [Here](https://www.mattbutton.com/2019/02/12/enabling-https-on-elastic-beanstalk-without-a-load-balancer/) is the best tutorial for SSL on single instance. The hassle is likely not worth the cost. Also, if you have other apps, you can use a shared load balancer (released Oct 2020)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you switch to single-instance, you will **not have ALB**. This means you can't use `AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener` in your ebextnations and you have to re-factor entire HTTPS handling.

Basically, you have to modify your EB to handle HTTPS by its own. If you used SSL cert from ACM, you have to get new one from a third party (not AWS), as **ACM certs can't be used** on your single-instance EB environment.

Comment: also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53655771